# send mails to many users in c sharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, sendmail

I'm working with c# in vs 2010, I made a class and method to send mail via smtp, I need 
  to send the same mail to many users, I made a list whith a query to select in my DB all 
  mails and not write them in my code, but I get this error message **"Attempt to access
  a socket not allowed by your access permissions"**, 
  and I can't send an email to many users, here is my code:

in  "send button"

```
private void enviar()
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    Enviar_Mail envi_mail = new Enviar_Mail();
    List<string> en_mail = envi_mail.SqlSelectMails();
    foreach (string mail_bci in en_mail)
    {
        msg.To.Add(mail_bci);
    }

    msg.From = new MailAddress("soporte.web@ipsos.com", "AaBb1234",
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

    msg.Subject = "prueba mails aviso y acusete bci";
    msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.Body = "saludos";
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("soporte.web", "AaBb1234");
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Host = "smtp0.chile.latam.ipsos";
    client.EnableSsl = false;
    try
    {
        client.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

in my class:

```
public List<string> SqlSelectMails()
{
    List<string> dir_mails = new List<string>();
    string stSql = "select mail_usuario from mail_usuario";
    Bd mibd = new Bd();
    SqlDataReader sdr = mibd.sqlExecute(stSql);
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        dir_mails.Add(sdr["mail_usuario"].ToString());
    }
    return dir_mails;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692064/what-caused-the-socket-exception-while-sending-email-from-console-application  ...someone else suggested their antivirus caused the issue.

Comment: Yes, I could see this message coming from an AV client that thinks it has just saved your machine from becoming a spam relay. Can you telnet from the machine in question to your mail server on port 25?

Comment: I already did, and I have no problems on port 25

Comment: Finally, the problem was the proxy in port 25, so I changed the server credentials (I've used other server and port 2025) and it works, thanks.