# Whitelist IP gmail smtp - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have the following code that sends an email. It works fine locally but when deploying on my hostgator windows server I get the exception below.

I would guess that I need to whitelist my servers IP in gmail somwhow but how do I do that?

Code:

```
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "From XXX");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "To XXX");
            const string fromPassword = "XXX";
            const string subject = "Email Headline";
            string body = "Email Body";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 173.194.77.109:587
```

Comment: Did you see these two: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12692064/231316 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10461257/231316

Comment: Yeah, but I think they are different. In their case it is their service that are blocking outgoing requests instead of Google's server blocking incoming requests...

Comment: This is a local Winsock error message, not remote, so Google isn't yet involved. Do you have access to firewall rules and/or AV? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx#WSAEACCES

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Hostgator , and I tried switching between many email service providers. But HG was blocking their SMTP sockets.

Now I'm sending mails from [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) using their REST API. **Use any Transactional Email Service API**. You'll get .Net clients for [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) and [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) in NuGet. Or you can call their API using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)